# Accessing HttpApplicationState where there is no current HttpContext available

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-4, application-state

Normally, when we need a reference to the current Application state, we'd use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Appliction
```

But there are times that there's no current HttpContext (`HttpContext.Current` returns `null`). How can I obtain a reference to the current application instance in that case?

An example can be in `Session_End` event. Although I can use `Application` property inside the `Session_End` event handler, but what if the handler calls a library method and the `HttpApplicationState` object is required in the library code? I don't like to pass an "application" parameter around...

I also don't like keeping it in a `static` field (like Singleton pattern) and I'm looking for a way to directly get it from context.

Is there any way to access the instance directly (similar to `HttpContext.Current.Application` approach) or do I have to choose one of the above not-so-clean methods?

Comment: I know when you have generic handler pages (IHttpHandler) you can implement IRequiresSessionState to make the state available.

Comment: There is nothing unclean about using a static/singleton pattern in this instance, in my opinion. In fact, I would encourage it.

Comment: @Moby I don't have any hard arguments against it, but I'd like something as clean and independent as `HttpContext.Current`. Consider the case where I'm writing a library code that wants access to Application, and another person wants to use it. If I define the Singleton, he still needs to fill it for me. If he defines it, I wouldn't have access to it. In this case, the best way can be writing a module and making him register it. Compare it to HttpContext.Current... It "could" be much easier and cleaner if the Framework gave us some options.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `HttpRuntime.Cache` instead of the application-state object. `HttpRuntime.Cache` can be used from anywhere.